# How to change folder permissions on a samba file server

Tags: server, permissions, samba, file-server

I have installed a samba file server on Ubuntu server machine in my office. Then I mapped the share on several various Windows PCs as a network drive. I have created folders in the root of the drive for each branch in the office. Now I want to prevent the users from creating more folders or files in the root of the mapped drive. But they should have the ability to make sub-folders and files inside already created folders. Is this possible?

Comment: The question has nothing to do with Ubuntu. It is about samba server not Ubuntu server. Also, if sambausers can write to the root dir of the server, it is terribly misconfigured.

Comment: @mikewhatever I actually meant the share folder not the actual root of the server  btw

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, I believe the answer is No.

Nevertheless here is what I did as a workaround.

Created two samba entries of the same folder, one is **read-only** and the other is **read-write**. Then I created a separated user for the read-write folder.

Thus only the PCs that are accessing the RW ISO folder with the user's credentials can make changes but all the others can only read the samba directory.

I know I am not answering your question but I hope that helps a bit.

```bash
[ISO]
    comment = ISO files
    path = /storage/ISO/
    browseable = yes
    writeable = no
    guest ok = yes

[ISO-RW]
    comment = ISO
    path = /storage/ISO/
    browseable = yes
    valid users = <user1>
    writable = yes
```